# 96人も遅刻するような学校なんだな。- Confusing use of ような

Tags: grammar

> 96人も遅刻する**ような**学校なんだな

In this sentence, I've done my best to translate as 'that is like 96 people being late for school'

but, ような here is confusing me. it makes me think of this sentence as 'that is like a school where 96 people are late'

Comment: Perhaps it means '96 people being late is similar to school' ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend a translation without the word *like*.

> 96人も遅刻するような学校なんだな
>   *So it's the kind of school where 96 people are late.*

Similar use cases:

- 困ったら{こまったら}すぐ噓{うそ}をつくような男だ
  *He's the kind of guy who will lie as soon as he's in trouble.*
- 口{くち}で言わなくてもわかるような関係{かんけい}だ
  *It's the kind of relationship where you can communicate without saying things out loud.*